# How to perform form validation in JSP/Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, validation

Currently I do something like this for each field where error message may be shown:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${message == null}">
    <label>Field name</label>
    <input type="text" name="field-name">
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <label class="error">Field name</label>
    <input type="text" name="field-name">
    <small class="error">${message}</small>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

How to DRY/make better this code? I don't want to repeat all that stuff every time when I need it in another field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look what you're repeating and then unify it. You're repeating the `<label>` and the `<input>` element. Just show them only once. You only need to add a class to the `<label>` and an additional element when there's a message.

```html
<label class="${not empty message ? 'error' : ''}">Field name</label>
<input type="text" name="field-name">
<c:if test="${not empty message}"><small class="error">${message}</small></c:if>
```

You can even omit the `<c:if>` altogeter, if there's no message, then the `<small>` won't appear in any way in the UI at all.

```html
<label class="${not empty message ? 'error' : ''}">Field name</label>
<input type="text" name="field-name">
<small class="error">${message}</small>
```

I'd only use a `<span>` instead of `<small>` as using the latter for this purpose is discouraged.

```html
<label class="${not empty message ? 'error' : ''}">Field name</label>
<input type="text" name="field-name">
<span class="error">${message}</span>
```

Comment: In the second snippet `<small class="error"></small>` appears in the UI

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using plain JSP (without any additional framework) then I'd suggest to create your own custom JSP tags. A `field` tag and a `message` tag. This will be kinda reinventing the wheel as many frameworks provide something like that if it's just your only requirement, then you could give it a try.

There is [Sun's tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html) about how to create your own tags, although a bit old but the internals haven't change so much and, even more, it will work with any servlet container as it is part of the standard.

I will give you the clues you need to write a simple `message` tag and I guess you'd be able to roll your own `field` one if you think you need it.

## Basic approach

Start creating a base class that extends the [`TagSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.html) abstract class and override the `doEndTag()` method. Check inside it if there is any `message` attribute in the current pageContext and, iif it exists, then print that error message through the tag's print stream:

```
public class MessageTag extends TagSupport {

    public int doEndTag() {
        String message = pageContext.findAttribute("message");
        if (message != null) {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.append("<small class=\"error\">").append(message).append("</small>");
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.println(output.toString());
        }
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }

}
```

Then follow the steps in the previous tutorial to define the tag library in your webapp and use it in your JSP:

```
<label>Field name</label>
<input type="text" name="field-name">
<mytags:message />
```

## Real world

That would be the simplest approach. But in a real world scenario, you'd like to show a different error message depending of the field you are validating so I will add an attribute `name` (or something similar) to the tag class and make it able to look for different messages depending of the value of that attribute:

```
public class MessageTag extends TagSupport {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void release() {
        super.release();
        name = null;
    }

    public int doEndTag() {
        String lookupAttr = (name != null ? name : "message");
        String message = pageContext.findAttribute(lookupAttr);
        if (message != null) {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.append("<small class=\"error\">").append(message).append("</small>");
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            out.println(output.toString());
        }
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }

}
```

That way you could reuse your tag for each specific field:

```
<label>Field name</label>
<input type="text" name="field-name">
<mytags:message name="field-name" />
```

Note that you will need to add the attribute definition to your tag library as well.

Obviously, you could make this as complex as you want (i.e.: adding a `style` attribute that could allow you to show INFO, WARNING or ERROR messages, etc.)

Comment: I use Apache Tiles 3 but I don't know how it can help me.

Comment: Apache Tiles is just a templating framework as long as I know, it won't help you with form validation. It would be different if you were using Struts, JSF, Spring MVC or any other *full featured* web framework. So, unless you want to switch to one of those, I would try the custom tags, it will take you a bit of time to get ready but at least your JSP code will look cleaner.

Comment: note that you could generate the code for the input field and the message itself in one single tag (let's name if `field`). I wrote here the code just for an hypothetical `message` tag for simplicity, the tutorial linked in the answer should give you enough knowledge to write a single tag class that could be able to render both items in the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do somehing like this`<input type="text" name="user" value="user">` Now read the value in the form where you want to use.You can use setAttribute() and getAttribute() methods
to get values in the new form.